# Local WAMP, network files

Tags: php, apache, wamp, alias, lan

I've tried creating some alias but it didn't work.
It is possible to run wamp installed on my pc, but the file's projects on other local network's pc?

Example:

```
Alias /server "//192.168.1.2/project_files" 
<Directory "//192.168.1.2/project_files">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So, I want that when I enter to http://localhost/server execute PHP reading the files from the other pc. When I configure this alias and I try to run wamp, Apache doesn't run (yellow wamp icon).

Comment: You want to run php files from another pc...maybe if it is a network unit you can do something like this: http://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows

Comment: Do you have WAMP or LAMP on 192.168.1.2 ?

Comment: No, my idea is that my local wamp execute the 19.168.1.2 files.

Comment: **Its not a good idea but it is possible** You have to share the folder on the NON-WAMP PC, then MAP a drive on the WAMP machine to point to the other PC's shared folder. Then it is recommended to use the Full UNC address in the `Alias` and `<Directory..` parameters

Comment: Oh and if you are using Apache 2.4 it is best to use the new 2.4 syntax instead of `Order allow,deny Allow from all` or `Require all granted` or better still just allow your subnet access using `Require ip 192.168.1`